# Azure elastic query to on prem setup

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm trying to set up an elastic query from an Azure database to an on premises SQL server.

I've got all the definitions done:

- Database Scoped Credential
- External Data Source (Type = RDBMS)
- External Table

  - The schema and names match perfectly

When I select top 1 * from the table I get the following error:

> Msg 46823, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
>   Error retrieving data from one or more shards.  The underlying error message received was: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'.

The credential was set up as a scoped credential and the External Data Source:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [DataSourceName] WITH    
(   
    TYPE = RDBMS, 
    LOCATION = '[IP]', 
    DATABASE_NAME = '[DBName]', 
    CREDENTIAL = [Credential] 
) ;
GO
```

External Table setup:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [schema].[table]
(
    [Columns]
)

WITH 
(DATA_SOURCE = [DataSourceName]) 
GO
```

My first question is if it is possible to connect from Azure to on premises with external tables?

If so, what might I be doing wrong?

Any and all advise would be much appreciated!

Comment: have you figured it out?